# Wpf Custom Popup control and application theming: Resources not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, themes

I have an app where I set a theme (`ResourceDictionary`) on the main Window. Then all children "inherits" styles, themes etc. via the `DynamicResourceExtension`. This works.

However, i have a custom Popup control to handle long press animation on buttons:

```
class LongPressAnimationControl : Popup
{
    static LongPressAnimationControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LongPressAnimationControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LongPressAnimationControl)));
    }
    /* Various DP's, events, properties, methods ETC. */
}
```

with a default style in `Generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:LongPressAnimationControl}">
    <Setter Property="Delay" Value="00:00:00.500" />
    <Setter Property="Duration" Value="00:00:01.000" />
    <Setter Property="Image" Value="{StaticResource Image.LongPress}" />
    <Setter Property="EasingFunction"><Setter.Value><CubicEase/></Setter.Value></Setter>
</Style>
```

This works. the properties change to the ones set in the style.

However, i would like the popup to use a style defined in the `Theme.xaml` so the properties etc. can be themed.

If i move the style to my `Theme.xaml`, then the style is not picked up (properties does not change). 
I've also tried to add a key to the Style, and a resource reference in code, like so:

```
public LongPressAnimationControl()
{
    SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, "LongPressAnimationControlStyle");
    //....
}
```

Anyone with an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Your Theame.xaml include in app resources?

Comment: Moved the Theme.xaml from the Main Window Resources to the App.xaml Resources and now it works.. Thank you @Firoz.

Comment: That's great i have update this as answer, so i might be useful for some else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include Theme.xaml in App.xaml resource, so WPF can find the resource.